# resize width of mat-form-field input field

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, material-design

[image: refrence image]

I have added matInput but I'm not able to resize it to full width of screen. I have not added any css to input fields.

```html
<form [formGroup]="LoginForm" class="" (ngSubmit)="OnLogin()">
  <div class="form-group">
    <mat-form-field class="mat-form-field-fluid">
      <input matInput placeholder="Enter Email" formControlName="email" required/>
      <mat-error> Email is
        <strong>required</strong>
      </mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-form-field class="mat-form-field-fluid">
      <input matInput placeholder="Enter Password" formControlName="password" required/>
      <mat-error> Password is
        <strong>required</strong>
      </mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? I usually alter the size of my fields by setting a css rule for mat-form-field and specifying the width property